# Using PHP to generate part of a background URL in CSS-file

Tags: php, html, css

I need PHP to generate part of a path name for my background image, which is used in a CSS-file. I changed the file type to PHP and added a header, as suggested in another post on StackOverflow. However, I cannot get it to work. I believe that the PHP generates and error and terminates all other code after that, but I am not sure how to acquire the error message. My code is:

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: text/css');
?>

body {
    min-height: 100%;
    background: url("<?php echo asset_url(); ?>images/backgroundImage.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center top;
}
```

The `asset_url()` function has been tested, and is working elsewhere, so that should not be the issue. An example of it working is here:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo asset_url(); ?>css/basicStyle.php">
```

Am I missing something totally obvious here?

**Update:**
I am pretty sure the CSS is loaded, as it worked before I changed it to PHP (I did not change anything else). An inspection of the site, once uploaded, shows the following in

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://e-drift.dk/assets/css/basicStyle.php">
```

However none of the CSS in the file is applied correctly, not a thing.

Comment: What does the css look like if you load the page?

Comment: Added an update to my main post, if that is what you meant.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you're including any required includes?

Your error message shows this;

> Call to undefined function asset_url() in
>   **/var/www/web/web694777/e-drift.dk/assets/css/basicStyle.php** on
>   line **7**

Comment: I am not including anything currently, as the function is usually made available through the CodeIgniter framework. However, it appears this is not the case here apparently.

Comment: I am working on a way to fix this, however I am now struggling on finding a command which provides the base path (either "http://e-drift.dk" or "http://e-drift.dk/application") so I dont have to hardcode the location. Any ideas?

Comment: @Noceo `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` (URL) or `realpath(__DIR__.'/../..')` (filesystem)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the source of the function `asset_url()` in `basicStyle.php` :

```
    include('file-with-function.php')
```

Answer (score 0):

Why would you save a Css file as a .php document?

Otherwise for your css document:

```
<?php
    header("Content-type: text/css; charset=utf-8");
?>
```